# Gitlab CI pipeline rules do not worked in combination of change and pipeline source

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am trying to run a pipeline job when the pipeline is run via web manually or when a specific file is changes. Both rules work separately as expected but in combination they do not.
My pipeline looks like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build-job:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
    - changes: 
      - bar.txt

  script:
    - echo $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE

unit-test-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "testing"
```

When I do a commit without changing bar.txt it works as expected and only job test is executed. When I start the pipeline manually or to changes on bar.txt it starts the job build-job as well, as expected.
But when I create a tag the build-job is also executed, although the variable CI_PIPLEINE_SOURCE is "push" and no changes where made to bar.txt.

If I only include one rule it all works as expected, even if I do a tag.

Can anyone see the mistake in my pipeline or do you think there is an error within gitlab CI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `changes` rule may evaluate to `true` for tag pushes, as explained in the documentation:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#jobs-or-pipelines-run-unexpectedly-when-using-changes

> Pipelines on branches or tags that don’t have an explicit association with a merge request use a previous SHA to calculate the diff. This calculation is equivalent to git diff HEAD~ and can cause unexpected behavior, including:
>
> - The changes rule always evaluates to true when pushing a new branch or a new tag to GitLab.
> - When pushing a new commit, the changed files are calculated by using the previous commit as the base SHA.

Comment: ok, that sadly explains it. Do you know any solution for my problem? Do I only have the solution to never build it on tags?

Comment: If you want to detect tag pipelines, maybe you can use the CI_COMMIT_TAG variable - it should be set only for tag pipelines: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#:~:text=of%20CI_COMMIT_SHA.-,CI_COMMIT_TAG,-9.0

Comment: ok then I really need to except tags. That was one solution I had but I thought it to be a bit weird. Thanks for the help!